# put button on top of image html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this:

```js
    var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    
    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
    .mySlides {
  /* max-width: 540px; */
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: repeat scroll center center / cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mySlides {
   display: none;
   max-width: 540px;
   height: 50vh;
   background: repeat scroll center center / cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerr" class="home">

    <div class="w3-content w3-section">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629220608817-0802c373e110?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">

    </div>
     
  </div>
```

basically, what I want is to put a `learn more` button on the image, in like the bottom left corner. I tried with just a standard button, but it goes right above of the image. How do i do this?

Comment: where is `learn more`  button ?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman He said the button stays above the image. There was no point to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set in your style sheet relative position for the parent element of the slider, then add the button and create a class for it where you define that its position will be absolute.

```js
  var myIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    
    function carousel() {
      var i;
      var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";  
      }
      myIndex++;
      if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
      x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
      setTimeout(carousel, 3000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    }
```

```css
.w3-content {
  position:relative;
}

.w3-content .button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:1em;
  left:1em;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: repeat scroll center center / cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mySlides {
   display: none;
   max-width: 540px;
   height: 50vh;
   background: repeat scroll center center / cover;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="headerr" class="home">
  <div class="w3-content w3-section">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629199022827-eede3c3df471?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <img class="mySlides" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1629220608817-0802c373e110?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwzfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60" style="width:100%">
    <button class="button" type="button">Learn more!</button>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Put your image into a separate `div` and give the div a `position: relative`

Now place your button inside that div and in its CSS, set its position to `position: absolute`.
This will adjust your button according to the container div.

Now, you may set the position of the button as you may like, for example add the following CSS in your button class `top: 5px; right: 50px`

Comment: This is a good idea, but if a mobile device were to go to the website, everything would be out of place because you are using pixels. It is better to use X%.

Comment: Yes, that's a great suggestion. Using percentage would be a much better option

Answer (score 1):

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_on_image.asp) has exactly what you want!